# Collapsable autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, collapsable

How do i implement collapsable autocomplete in Jquery. I have a group and a group can have zero or many items. How do i implement this in Jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: I wouldlike a tree view inside an autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete an input field to enable users quickly finding and selecting some value, leveraging searching and filtering.

By giving an autocompleted field focus or entering something into it, the plugin starts searching for matching entries and displays a list of values to choose from. By entering more characters, the user can filter down the list to better matches.

This can be used to enter previous selected values, eg. for tags, to complete an address, eg. enter a city name and get the zip code, or maybe enter email addresses from an addressbook.

[Please see the documentation for more details.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete)